# How early should I arrive at Logan (Boston) for a weekday late-afternoon flight?

Tags: air-travel, usa, airports, boston, bos

I know that the question of how early to arrive at the airport [depends on the airport and how busy it is at particular times](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4105/2406).  For a domestic flight leaving Logan (Boston) on a Tuesday at 6:30PM, with no checked baggage, how much time should I allow to get through security and to the correct terminal/gate?  I do not have any privileged status (airline clubs, expedited security, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boston Logan is one of the most efficient airports I have flown in and out of. It is also a huge airport. From my experience, if you don't require assistance, I reckon you be at the airport at least an hour before your flight departs.

Comment: I got there earlier than I needed to and went from the curb-side drop-off to the gate in about an hour.